# Invalid handler for event "xxx": got undefined

Tags: vue.js, events, undefined, handler

I am trying to emit an event from a child component to a parent component, no variables passed or nothing, just a trigger.

```html
<div id="app">
    <app-wrapper v-on:lang-change="updateLang">
    </app-wrapper>
  </div>
```

```js
var appWrapper = {
  components: {
    'videoheader': videoHeader,
    'languagebuttons': langButtons
  },
  template: `
        <div>
          <languagebuttons></languagebuttons>
          <videoheader></videoheader>
        </div>
`,
  data() {
    return {
      langOptions: ["nl", "en"]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    currentLang(){ return this.langOptions[1] }
  },
  methods: {
    updateLang(){
      if (this.currentLang === this.langOptions.indexOf(0))
        this.currentLang = this.langOptions[1];
      else
        this.currentLang = this.langOptions[0];

      console.log(this.currentLang)
    }
  }
};


Vue.component('app-wrapper', appWrapper);
```

The event is emitted and registered by the Vue devtools, but for some reason the updateLang method either doesn't activate, or I get an error (more common) that the method updateLang is undefined.

Comment: You seem to be listening in the wrong template. The `v-on` part needs to be moved into the template defined inside `appWrapper`, on whichever of the two children emits the event.

Comment: YES! that did it. I was looking at templates for this event thing and didn't notice the position of the event-to-handler binding. Thank you!

Comment: It's not fully solved though since I still don't understand where to place the v-on part. Trying to add another v-on right now where it listens to a sibling component, which also does not seem to respond, the method is undefined again. Vue doesn't have great documentation on this.

Comment: The parent listens to its children, so the `v-on` always goes in the parent's template and is an attribute of the relevant child. Siblings cannot listen to each other directly. The simplest solution is for the parent to hold the relevant data and pass it to the children via props, updating that data in response to child events. Vuex is an alternative solution that bypasses the parent by using global state instead.